# How to restart a Kubernetes deployment from a Jenkins pod

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, payara

I need to restart another Kubernetes like
`kubectl rollout restart -n nams deployment xxx-deployment`
deployment from a Jenkins server running inside the same Kubernetes cluster.

How to do that?

I was already tried without success with Jenkins Build Agents. I have a kubernetes pod that runs a Payara application server and I need to restart the deployment to take effect a new version off the deployed application.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the `image:` in your Deployment spec to reflect a new image tag as built by your CI pipeline.  Tools like Kustomize and Helm can help inject this value.  If you can change the image name then Kubernetes will recreate the Pods on its own and you won't need this restart step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Kubernetes CLI plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/) on your Jenkins. With this plugin, it does not matter what platform your Jenkins is running on as long as your target Kubernetes cluster API endpoint is accessible by the Jenkins.

All your jobs will have the option to specify the Kubernetes cluster connection details in the `Build Environment` section.

[image: build environment]

Then, add an `Execute Shell` build step where you can happily use the `kubectl` commands however you want.

[image: build step]

--- ADDITIONAL INFO ---

Here is the script for creating the `kubectl-token` needed by the plugin. Just modify `KUBE_NS` variable to the name of the particular namespace in which the job will be run:

```
#!/bin/bash

KUBE_NS="default"

if [[ ! -n $(kubectl get ns --field-selector=metadata.name=${KUBE_NS} --no-headers 2> /dev/null) ]]; then
  echo Namespace $KUBE_NS not found!
  exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -n "${SA_NAME}" ]]; then
  SA_NAME=sa-${KUBE_CLUSTER}-${KUBE_NS}
fi

kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: ${KUBE_NS}
  name: ${SA_NAME}
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: ${KUBE_NS}
  name: ${SA_NAME}-edit-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ${SA_NAME}
  namespace: ${KUBE_NS}
EOF

SA_SECRET=$(kubectl get -n ${KUBE_NS} serviceaccount/${SA_NAME} -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
if [[ ! -n "${SA_SECRET}" ]]; then
SA_SECRET="${SA_NAME}-token"
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: ${SA_SECRET}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "${SA_NAME}"
EOF
fi
TOKEN=$(kubectl get -n ${KUBE_NS} secret/${SA_SECRET} -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukman one more thing, how to create kubectl-token on Credentials?

Comment: @Giorgos, I've added the script to my answer above.

Comment: I get the following error after build the job:

`Started by user Administrator
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/kube
[kube] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins11498915247631690849.sh
+ kubectl get pods
/tmp/jenkins11498915247631690849.sh: 2: kubectl: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[kubernetes-cli] kubectl configuration cleaned up
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: @Giorgos, did you fulfill the plugin's requirements?: https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/#plugin-content-prerequisites

Comment: yes missing the `kubectl` executor.


One possible way to get kubectl is to install it in the Jenkins pipeline like in the snipped below:
NOTE: I'm using ./kubectl get pods to list all Pods in the default Namespace. Additionally, you may need to change kubectl version (v1.20.5).
`node {
  stage('List pods') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'kubernetes-config']) {
        sh 'curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'  
        sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'  
        sh './kubectl get pods'
    }
  }
}`